# How to extract the result of a multiply blend from the underlaying layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In Photoshop I have a layer A which is placed onto another layer B using a multiple blend. The result looks good.

Now, I wish to hide layer B so that layer A can be saved out as a semi-transparent PNG and used on a web page which has B as a background. The alignment may not be perfect, so I don't wish to include the background in this PNG.

The problem, of course, is that as soon as I hide B layer A returns to it's original colours since there's no longer anything to multiply with. What I need is a way of fixing the result of the blend - the colour shifts that A was subjected to - such that I can remove B.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: I'm just gonna leave this here http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10618/export-layers-with-bleding-options-and-shadow-to-png-format-using-photoshop/10642#10642

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the layers? The content will likely dictate the best approach.

Answer (score 15):

I was having the same problem and I ended up used the background eraser tool.  Basically the Multiply tool is getting rid of all the white in your image. This tool does the same but instead deletes it and is not based on the layer below.

Take the layer that you would have on top (in your case layer A) and use the background eraser tool on a low tolerance. Test until you find the perfect number (in my case it was about 20). Also make sure it's clicked to 'sampling: background swatch' and make sure your background swatch color is white.

It worked quite well for me; I hope it works for you too.

Comment: After almost 2 hours of searching I stumbled upon your solution. I can't thank you enough!

Comment: You should format your answer, It looks like a long boring paragraph. I actually skimmed it at first but later realized your solution works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The only solution I found is to use a script that my collegue found somewhere online. It can take a (pixel layers, no adjustment layers) from screen mode into normal mode while keeping its appearance. Now Multiply is the opposite of screen so you can use it also for this.

1: put your (pixel) layer from multiply to normal mode
2: invert layer (ctrl+I)
3: run the `byebyescreenmode` script with your layer active
4: invert again

Now you will have a layer that is in normal mode and looks for 95% indentical to your original multiply layer (might have small color shift).
If you use it de get rid of a screen blending mode it will look 100% the same.

You can download the script here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14DAOkZT1dUV1cmv-22lSktUHQC8I0q-X/view?usp=sharing

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hello Ronen, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions about this site, please have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you merge visible then mask or remove anything not effected by the blend mode.

This question asks a similar thing involving Overlay mode. Same solution though.
[Photoshop — convert 'overlay' layer to normal](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9176/photoshop-convert-overlay-layer-to-normal)

Comment: Hi. That technique would fix the background image into the result, whereas I need to maintain the transparency so that I can position it on another background. Essentially I need to keep only the colour shifts that occur.

Comment: That is not possible. In order for blending modes to work there must be layers of pixels. There is no feasible way to have a blend mode alter anything with only a single layer. None. I still think this technique I posted may work. Can you add a sample image to your question?

Comment: Another option would be use the eyedropper to pick up the resulting color, then apply that color to an independent layer in the necessary shape.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a blending mode, try using opacity on layer A. It is limiting, but you can export it out as a PNG and it will work when overlayed on the website.

Answer (score 0):

For me, what worked was simply removing the light from my shadows. For example, I had an image with a shadow below it, the shadow being a separate layer. When I turned the shadow on "multiply" it looked great, but looked awful when I saved it for web with a transparent background because the multiply blend was gone and the white parts that were being used to create a gradient effect on the shadow still showed up.

Solution: I selected the shadow layer, went into Image>Adjustment, and turned down the Lightness completely. Then I set that layer to a lower opacity and saved for web. Voilà!

Comment: can you add some images to show the results?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using channels (after looking at [this article by PSD-Dude](http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/convert-image-to-layer-mask-in-photoshop-using-channels.aspx)). Here are the steps:

1. Copy your texture layer.
2. Invert the colors of the new layer (should end up mostly black).
3. With just the new layer showing, select all and copy.
4. Create a new solid fill layer, set to black.
5. Hide other layers, select the mask, and move over to the Channels tab.
6. Show the mask.
7. Paste the texture copied in step 3 into the mask.
8. Move back to the Layers tab and select another layer to leave mask mode.

At this point you can export the PNG. I ended up messing with the brightness/contrast of the mask and opacity of the layer for a while.