# Homogeneous color of object

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to achieve the effect bellow (source: Twitter official blog header image).

I have a background color and a few colorful flat objects that I want to bend into the background color like bellow.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62693/transparent-pattern-background-overlay-issue/62697#62697 Transparent Pattern Background Overlay Issue? It is just about the same question

Answer (score 0):

Easiest & Fastest, non-destructive (important) way would be to create a **"Gradient Map" Adjustment Layer**. Put this layer on top and create a gradient from **"#327db6"** colour to **"#5399d4"**

You will have to play around with placements of the colours on a gradient as it all depends on the underlying brightness of the colour.

With a default gradient, all the bright/white colours will change to the colour on the side of a gradient and all the dark/Black colours will be matched to the colours on the left side of the gradient.  Unless you check "Reverse".

The reason why you would use gradient map over blending modes:

- much more control over what colours get changed to what colour
- You just need 1 layer which controls all underlying items
- A totally non-destructive way
- is much less confusing if you have a lot of layers underneath